# Including an icon in From field, for email sent through the Amazon Simple Email Service

Tags: smtp, amazon-ses

I have been using the Amazon Simple Email Service (SES) for several of my applications.

I receive emails, with an icon/image in the From field (to the left of the From field.

Any idea how to do this from SES?